# Is it valid to have multiple form input elements with the same name?

Tags: html, forms, w3c-validation

Is it valid markup and is it valid to the HTML/HTTP spec?  If I wanted to have

```
<form>
<input name="email" />
<input name="email" />
<input name="email" />
</form>
```

is that valid?

Comment: By definition, radio buttons in the same group have the same name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [stated on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452066/html-form-with-multiple-hidden-control-elements-of-the-same-name):

> The browsers are OK with it. However,
>   how the application library parses it
>   may vary.
>
> Programs are supposed to group
>   identically named items together.
>   While the HTML specification doesn't
>   explicitly say this, it is implicitly
>   stated in the documentation on
>   checkboxes:
>
> *"Several checkboxes in a form may share
>   the same control name. Thus, for
>   example, checkboxes allow users to
>   select several values for the same
>   property."*

On a side note, in PHP you can have form fields with the same name if you use PHP's arry syntax for the  field name:

```
<form>
<input name="email[]" />
<input name="email[]" />
<input name="email[]" />
</form>
```

This will cause the browser to send over the form fields in a syntax that PHP will use to populate an array for these fields: `$_REQUEST['email']`. If you use PHP this is the preferred way to handle it.

Answer (score 9):

**HTML5**

The non-normative section [4.10.1.3 Configuring a form to communicate with a server](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#configuring-a-form-to-communicate-with-a-server) explicitly says that it is valid:

> Multiple controls can have the same name; for example, here we give all the checkboxes the same name, and the server distinguishes which checkbox was checked by seeing which values are submitted with that name — like the radio buttons, they are also given unique values with the value attribute.

The normative version of this is simply that it is not forbidden anywhere, and the form submission algorithm says exactly what request should be generated:

- no constraint is violated: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constraints
- multiple names get added to the "form data set" one after the other: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#sec-constructing-the-form-data-set
- encodings like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` loop over the "form data set" and spit out multiple `key=val` https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data

Answer (score 1):

Yes the markup

```
<form>
<input name="email">
<input name="email">
<input name="email">
</form>
```

is valid: in fact it is possible and it is OK to use the same **name** multiple times into a form or even into the same document, but it **is not** the use of the same **ID** that must be **unique into the whole document/page**.
AFAIK, an exception is in HTML5 where is required that a form's name has to be unique if the page contains multiple forms. But the elements' names even doesn't matter if in the same form or in different forms in the same document can be duplicated.
The address https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-name reports the spec and you can find the following info:

> The name attribute represents the form's name within the forms
> collection. The value must not be the empty string, and the value must
> be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection that it is
> in, if any.

The **form collection** can be accessed/selected with `document.forms`.

Notice that the html elements will be rendered in any case by browsers, even if they have duplicate ids, because browser are error tolerant in this case, but the problem is the formal validation and if the elements have to be manipulated with some script: in fact notice for example that:

- in case of multiple elements sharing the same **id**, only the first hit will be returned by selection functions/methods like `getElementById()` or `querySelector()`etc.
- in case of multiple elements sharing the same **name** all elements will be returned by selection functions/methods like `getElementsByName()` (notice the "**s**" at the end of **Elements**) or `querySelectorAll()`. Of course `querySelector()` will only return the first hit in any case.